# Apache: scope for environmental variables

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite, environment-variables

While there's documentation available on Apache environmental variables, I can not find answer to one important question. Imagine I use rewrite rules to set environmental variable

```
RewriteRule ... ... [E=something:1]
```

What is the scope of "something" - global Apache server (this means "something" will be available for other request transactions), this request (means that "something" is only valid for THIS http request (and its related processing - but what's about internal redirects and other internal stuff - are they considered as THIS request, or another one?), and may be set differently within another (concurrent) request?

Answer (score 2):

The scope is this request and can be set differently in another concurrent request. The relevant part of the docs is this:

> **Conditional Per-Request Settings**
>
> For additional flexibility, the directives provided by mod_setenvif
>   allow environment variables to be set on a per-request basis,
>   conditional on characteristics of particular requests. For example, a
>   variable could be set only when a specific browser (User-Agent) is
>   making a request, or only when a specific Referer [sic] header is
>   found. Even more flexibility is available through the mod_rewrite's
>   RewriteRule which uses the [E=...] option to set environment
>   variables.

[source](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/env.html)

Comment: It says "ALLOW ... TO BE SET", but does not clearly state that if I set env var it will be specific to request. If I am allowed to do something, it does not mean I will get behavior I need. It should be "the directives provided by mod_setenvif SET environment variables on a per-request basis, conditional on characteristics of particular request". Then it is clear.

Comment: Did you skip the title? It clearly says Conditional **Per-Request** Settings, meaning that if you set them using Setenv_if or the flag E in mod_rewrite, these are set per-request.

Comment: If its name would be "per-request setting", it would be more clear than it is with "conditional" word. Also, let's look at this statement: "For example, a variable could be set only when a specific browser (User-Agent) is making a request, or only when a specific Referer [sic] header is found". Literally it means if there're several sessions with same User-Agent (e.g. desktop) they will get SAME environment variable in SAME state. Also, if there're two sessions from same referral, these sessions will also receive same variable, even if they are expected to be different (eg.depending on cookie)

Comment: Yes, the same environment variable would have the same state, but that variable would be set on a per-request basis: A request arrives, we look at it's user-agent and set the environment variable. When other request arrives, for that request, the variable is unset until we look at its user-agent and (in that precise moment ) we set it to the same value than before.

Comment: Who - "we"? You mean _some custom_ code in httpd.conf or .htaccess (speaking about "examples" in the original Apache manual page)? It should be clearly and explicitly explained on that page. The logic how it works/explained is not clear. These examples should be backed up by the code.

Comment: I was trying to explain you how that works from the server point of view, but I don't think we are moving forward. The docs are crystal clear on what is the scope of the environmental-variables when set through the E flag. The 'conditional' part that bothers you, simply means that they are set if a condition is met (the condition on the RewriteRule or the condition on the mod_setenvif directive).